# Extracting a specific part of a string

Tags: php, string, codeigniter, extract

I have this string:

```
[25-03-15, 1236], [26-03-15, 3000], [27-03-15, 3054], [30-03-15, 4000]
```

I want to get two parts from it as below:

```
['25-03-15','26-03-15','27-03-15','30-03-2015']
```

and

```
[1236,3000,3054,4000]
```

Please guide me how I can perform this task.

PS: I am working of view page of codeigniter.

I'm getting the first thing as:

```
<?php 
$usd=$this->db->query('select transaction_date, SUM(amount) as total 
from transactions GROUP BY transaction_date')->result_array();
$str = '';

for($i=0; $i<count($usd); $i++){
    if($i!=0){
        $str = $str.', ['.date('d-m-y', strtotime($usd[$i]["transaction_date"])).', '.$usd[$i]["total"].']';
    }else{
        $str = $str.'['.date('d-m-y', strtotime($usd[$i]["transaction_date"])).', '.$usd[$i]["total"].']';
    }
}

echo $str;

?>
```

Comment: the very first one in your question one is array or string?

Comment: Is it a string, 4 different arrays or 1 multidimensional array?

Comment: I hope it is a string

Comment: @ShahidRafiq So this: `[25-03-15, 1236], [26-03-15, 3000], [27-03-15, 3054], [30-03-15, 4000]` is a string not an array? If yes why did you tagged it with array and wrote array in the title?

Comment: I said i hope, Please check the question again, @Rizier123 I mentioned string or array, any how I have edited the question to explain what kind of thing it is

Comment: @ShahidRafiq Why do you save the data in a string?? That makes is just very complicated to extract the data which you want!

Comment: I will pass this extracted data to a graph that accepts this kind of data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
  $date = '';
  $total = '';
for($i=0; $i<count($usd); $i++){
    if($i!=0){
        $date .= date('d-m-y', strtotime($usd[$i]["transaction_date"])).', ';
         $total .= $usd[$i]["total"].', ';

    }else{
         $date .= date('d-m-y', strtotime($usd[$i]["transaction_date"])).', ';
         $total .= $usd[$i]["total"].', ';
    }
}

 echo $finaldate='['. $date.']';
  echo $finaltotal='['. $total.']';
```

Comment: [25-03-15, 26-03-15, 27-03-15, 30-03-15, ] in this ['25-03-15','26-03-15','27-03-15','30-03-2015']   and same about the total Thank you

Comment: @Jocker *Please accept my answer if it is correct* are you begging for reputation?! (BTW: It is not a good idea to store the data in a string, since it's very hard to maintain!)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any reason why you need to save this data from your db in a string. Just save it in an array and it is that easy:

So here I save your data in an array, so that you get this structure:

```
array(
    array(25-03-15, 1236),
    array(26-03-15, 3000),
    array(27-03-15, 3054),
    array(30-03-15, 4000)
)
```

The you can simply use [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to extract the single columns, like this:

```
<?php

    $usd = $this->db->query('select transaction_date, SUM(amount) as total 
    from transactions GROUP BY transaction_date')->result_array();

    foreach($usd as $k => $v)
        $result[] = [date('d-m-y', strtotime($usd[$k]["transaction_date"])), $usd[$k]["total"]];


    $partOne = array_column($result, 0);
    $partTwo = array_column($result, 1);

?>
```

Also if you then need this data in a string as you said in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29388232/extracting-a-specific-part-of-a-string/29388452#comment46954365_29388232) you can simply transform it:

> I will pass this extracted data to a graph that accepts this kind of data –  Shahid Rafiq 6 mins ago

Just use this:

```
echo $str = "[" . implode("],[", array_map(function($v){
    return implode(",", $v);
}, $usd)) . "]";
```

output:

```
[25-03-15, 1236], [26-03-15, 3000], [27-03-15, 3054], [30-03-15, 4000]
```

**EDIT:**

If you also want the parts as string just simply do this:

```
$partOne = "[" . implode("],[", array_column($arr, 0)) . "]";
$partTwo = "[" . implode("],[", array_column($arr, 1)) . "]";
```

output:

```
[25-03-15],[26-03-15],[27-03-15],[30-03-15]
[1236],[3000],[3054],[4000]
```

Comment: no, I need a string like this ['25-03-15','26-03-15','27-03-15','30-03-2015'] to make input for a graph I have selected. Thank you

Comment: @ShahidRafiq You mean you need the parts also as strings :D?

Comment: Yes, I need resulted parts in string , too .  :)

Comment: @ShahidRafiq Ah ok, just updated my answer! Hopefully this helps you. Just please don't store your data in a simple string